# Linq Group BY Multiple Values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, group-by

im making a group by out of my Model in MVC i manage to get my 3 principal values but i dont know how to add more data to my select in the linq.

**This is my Linq Statement:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(a => a.Pla).Select(p => new { Pla = p.Key, Quantity = p.Sum(q => q.Cantidad), Total = p.Sum(x => x.Total) }))
```

**This is my Table:**

```
Con   Fecha           Rid       Pdv   Pla   Descripcion       Total Quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     2016-01-01    COMIDAS    FUEM   184   POZ ROJO           1445    17
100   2016-01-01    COMIDAS    VTSI   693   ENVASE 1 LT         50     5
103   2016-01-01    COMIDAS    REST   73    NOPAL/PIÑA VASO     34     6
104   2016-01-01    DESAYUNOS  REST   73    NOPAL/PIÑA VASO     34     1
```

This gives me the unique `Pla` items and the sum of `Total` and `Quantity` data, but i need to also display 3 more columns `desc`, `Rid` and `Pdv`
How can i add them to my Linq?

**First Try**

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.GroupBy(a=> a.Pla).Select(p=> new     
{Pdv = p.Pdv, Pla = p.Key, Nombre=p.Descripcion, Rid=p.Rid, Quantity = p.Sum(q=>q.Cantidad), Total= p.Sum(x=>x.Total)}))
{
  listItemPopu.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

This is my First Attemp but i cannot get it to work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your pla is grouped by key, every group has a list of plas, with a unique key, and all plas in a group have the same Pdv, Description, Riv.

You can actually get the 3 fields from the key you already extracted out.

```
{
  var pdv = item.Pla.Pdv; // etc.

  listItemPopu.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

But if you don't want to do that, because you cannot apply sum to string fields, you need to do a FirstOrDefault on them.

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.GroupBy(a=> a.Pla).Select(p=> new     
{
  Pla = p.Key, 
  Pdv = p.Select(a => a.Pdv).FirstOrDefault(),
  Nombre = p.Select(a => a.Description).FirstOrDefault(), 
  Rid = p.Select(a => a.Rid).FirstOrDefault(), 
  Quantity = p.Sum(q=>q.Cantidad), 
  Total= p.Sum(x=>x.Total)
}))

{
  listItemPopu.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

and if your 3 fields are from the pla itself, you can also base it off the key.

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.GroupBy(a=> a.Pla).Select(p=> new     
{
  Pla = p.Key, 
  Pdv = p.Key.Pdv,
  Nombre = p.Key.Description, 
  Rid = p.Key.Rid, 
  Quantity = p.Sum(q=>q.Cantidad), 
  Total= p.Sum(x=>x.Total)
}))

{
  listItemPopu.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Rid looks like it can be different for the same Pla, which may be an issue.